# TextBoxFor id is missing in custom helper when using it in vbhtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

i have used TextBoxFor control in my custom helper. and it does not generate id attribute. Is it a known issue? or am i doing wrong any thing in my custom helper ? i have given my code below,

```js
App_Code/customhelper.vbhtml
@Import System.Web.Mvc
@Import System.Web.Mvc.Html
@ModelType EditorVB.DateSettings

@Helper  MyHelper(ByVal page As WebViewPage, ByVal model As EditorVB.DateSettings)
    
    @page.Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) model.EndDate)

End Helper

Views/index.vbhtml
@ModelType EditorVB.DateSettings
@CustomHelper.MyHelper(PageContext.Page, Model)

DateSettings.vb
Public Class DateSettings
    Public Property EndDate() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_EndDate
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_EndDate = value
        End Set
    End Property    
    Private m_EndDate As DateTime
```

Comment: "*it does not generate id attribute*" — what *does* it do?

Comment: What does this helper do that the standard `@Html.TextBoxFor()` method does not already do?

Comment: i'm using this custom helper as generic. Also, when we using this outside the customer helper or in cshtml page it generates id for the textbox.

Comment: any solution for this issue?